# Merge two sequential models on Keras for hybrid model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, hybrid

I want to combine two sequential models for a hybrid model (with Keras 2.6.0). The first model is a succession of dense layer of a set of 4 parameters, and the second is a succession of 2D convolution of an image ((32,32)). The goal is to predict a curve of 128 points.

[image: Here is an illustration of my model hybrid idea.]

My actual model:

```
def get_model_v2(params_shape, img_shape):
    params_model = models.Sequential()
    params_model.add(layers.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu', name='Dense_n1'))
    params_model.add(layers.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu', name='Dense_n2'))
    params_model.add(layers.Dense(256, name='Output'))
    
    img_model = models.Sequential()
    img_model.add(layers.Input(img_shape, name='InputLayer2'))
    img_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    img_model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    img_model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    img_model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    img_model.add(layers.Flatten())
    
    concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([params_model, img_model])

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input(concat, name='InputLayer3'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu', name='Dense_n1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, name='Output'))
    
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
                  loss      = 'mse', 
                  metrics   = ['mae', 'mse'])
    return model


model = get_model_v2 ( (4,),  (32, 32, 1) )
```

My problem is when I have to combine the two models, I don't know what to use, with this "concatenate" example I have an error like: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. I understand the problem, but I can't find an other solution...

Comment: You fully need to use the Functional API, you have a strange mix of both APIs which does not make sense. Only use the Functional API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here,

- You are not using `params_shape` for your `params_model` (which comes out with an undefined shape).
- As you understood, you can't concatenate models with a concatenation layer
- The final model needs to through the `Functional API`
- You got a bunch of layers with same name - you cannot have the same name for two layers in the same model

```
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow.keras.models as models
import tensorflow.keras.regularizers as regularizers
import tensorflow as tf

def get_model_v2(params_shape, img_shape):
    params_model = models.Sequential()
    params_model.add(layers.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu', name='Dense_n1', input_shape=params_shape))
    params_model.add(layers.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu', name='Dense_n2'))
    params_model.add(layers.Dense(256, name='Output'))
    
    img_model = models.Sequential()
    img_model.add(layers.Input(img_shape, name='InputLayer2'))
    img_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    img_model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    img_model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    img_model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    img_model.add(layers.Flatten())
    
    param_out = params_model.outputs[0]
    img_out = img_model.outputs[0]

    concat_out = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([param_out, img_out])

    full_dense_out = layers.Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu', name='Dense_n3')(concat_out)
    final_out = layers.Dense(128, name='Output_final')(full_dense_out)
    
    model = models.Model(inputs=[params_model.inputs, img_model.inputs], outputs=final_out)

    model.summary()

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
                  loss      = 'mse', 
                  metrics   = ['mae', 'mse'])
    return model


model = get_model_v2 ( (4,),  (32, 32, 1) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As suggested by @Dr. Snoopy I also redid the model using only the Functional API and the model seems to work. Your answer helps me a lot to understand the (many) problems of my initial model, I will test your correction and then decide if I continue with the Sequential or not.